# Boost Graph Library: Error while compiling with make_reverse_graph

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, boost-graph

I get a lot of errors when compiling while using the function `make_reverse_graph` of the Boost Graph Library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be sure that your graph is defined as `boost::bidirectionalS`.
This means that there is for each vertex a list of its in-edges, which makes the reversion of the graph much more efficient.